# Is there a way to create a @media rule with kind of formula that describes the dependency between element CSS padding and max-width property?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

There is a **div** that changes its **padding-left** CSS value depending on the page width. The padding value increases when page width decreases. If the page width is 1800px then the padding is 0px, if width=1700px then padding=10px, in other words:

```
|N| Page width | padding-left |
|-| -----------| ------------ |
|1| 1800px     | 0px          |
|2| 1700px     | 10px         |
|3| 1600px     | 20px         |
|.| ...        | ...          |
|9| 1000px     | 80px         |
```

For that, there were created 9 **@media** rules as shown below

```
@media (max-width: 1800px) {
    .my-padding {
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1700px) {
    .my-padding {
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
}
...
...
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .my-padding {
        padding-left: 80px;
    }
}
```

Question: is there a way to create only one **@media** rule but to include a kind of *formula* that describes the dependency between CSS **padding** and **max-width** property?
One solution can be to generate a separate CSS file programmatically with 9 desired **@media** rules

The formula for calculating the **padding-left** value can be the following:

`padding-left = ((1800px - current_page_width) / 100) * 10`

The problem is I do not know how to apply it

Comment: It's not clear what you want for me. Use a combination of css properties in combination with calc()?

Comment: Do you know how to use SASS/SCSS? If so, there may be a solution to handle the media query output

Comment: Even with Sass etc it will still pump out the same number of rules. The preprocessor just makes it easier to write.

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah, of course. I'm wondering if OP is trying to streamline the process. EDIT: I just reread and saw _ONE `@media` rule_ EDIT 2: but then the next line is to generate separate CSS files. Not sure what the goal here is

Comment: you can shorten the code with css var() rule and reset that var only in the mediaquerie : `@media (max-width: xx ) {:root{--pl:xx}}` and in the main CSS `.my-padding{padding-left:var(--pl);}`once for all :) (you probably need those mediaquerie for other rules ;)

Comment: the goal is to have **only one universal @media rule** if it is possible, having 9 rules by writing them manually or programmatically is not an elegant solution

Comment: `padding-left: calc( (1800px - 100vw  ) * 0.1 );`will not require any mediaquerie ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `padding-left = ((1800 - current_page_width)/100)*10`

Could be : `padding-left: calc( (1800px - 100vw  ) * 0.1 );`

demo

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: calc( (1800px - 100vw) * 0.1);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, gray 0 10px, transparent 10px 20px);
}
```

```html
<div style="border:solid;">div</div>
```

Comment: or even `calc(180px - 10vw)`

Comment: and maybe `max(0, calc(180px - 10vw))` to avoid invalid negative values =))

Comment: @Kosh, max() with the formula inside works very well in Chrome but not in Microsoft Edge, so I do not apply it, and it seems both browsers just ignore the negative padding value

Comment: @Igor as soon as the value is negative, it is not applied because it is not a valid value (negative if applied value would probably pull outside the content , also box-sing will reduce the value if the box's size is too small to apply it ) . Latest edge uses chrome engines to render CSS , it should be similar.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus: 1. [it is not applied] = [ignored] 2. I have tried exactly your good solution with max CSS function. **max(0, calc( (1800px - 100vw) * 0.1))** First I have tried localy in my project and it does not work in Edge, after that have tried here in stackoverflow **Code Snippet** tool and again it was not working in Edge, only in Chrome

Comment: @Igor, you might check browser support [here](https://caniuse.com/css-math-functions), and you're right Edge versions 12-18 **do not** support `max()`. Also, please keep in mind that if the element has `padding-left` that was set before, invalid ignored value won't reset it.

Answer (score 2):

I've inverted your media query to follow specified sizes -- it's calculating padding-left: -# over 1800px but doesn't render (padding negatives are invalid). Using calc below:

```
.my-padding {
  padding-left: 80px;
}
@media (min-width: 1001px) {
 .my-padding {
   padding-left: calc((1800px - 100vw)/10);
 }
}
```

You can use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) to create formulas in CSS. vw and vh units are 1% of viewport width or height -- 100vw is 100% viewport width. I've run into situations where VW/VH does and doesn't include the scrollbars so some tweaking may be needed.